# Swift: downloading data from url causes semaphore_wait_trap freeze

Tags: ios, swift, semaphore, nsoperationqueue

In my application, button tapping downloads data from an Internet site. The site is a list of links containing binary data. Sometimes, the first link may not contain the proper data. In this case, the application takes the next link in the array and gets data from there. The links are correct.

The problem I have is that frequently (not always though) the application freezes for seconds when I tap on the button. After 5-30 seconds, it unfreezes and downloading implements normally. I understand, something is blocking the main thread. When stopping the process in xCode, I get this (semaphore_wait_trap noted):

[image]

This is how I do it:

```
// Button Action
@IBAction func downloadWindNoaa(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
            // Starts activity indicator
            startActivityIndicator()

            // Starts downloading and processing data

            // Either use this
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async
                {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async
                        {
                            self.downloadWindsAloftData()
                        }
                }


            // Or this - no difference.
            //downloadWindsAloftData()
        }
    }

func downloadWindsAloftData()
    {
        // Creates a list of website addresses to request data: CHECKED.
        self.listOfLinks = makeGribWebAddress()

        // Extract and save the data
        saveGribFile()
    }

// This downloads the data and saves it in a required format. I suspect, this is the culprit

    func saveGribFile()
    {
        // Check if the links have been created
        if (!self.listOfLinks.isEmpty)
        {
            /// Instance of OperationQueue
            queue = OperationQueue()

            // Convert array of Strings to array of URL links
            let urls = self.listOfLinks.map { URL(string: $0)! }

            guard self.urlIndex != urls.count else
            {
                NSLog("report failure")
                return
            }

            // Current link
            let url = urls[self.urlIndex]

            // Increment the url index
            self.urlIndex += 1

            // Add operation to the queue
            queue.addOperation { () -> Void in

                // Variables for Request, Queue, and Error
                let request = URLRequest(url: url)
                let session = URLSession.shared

                // Array of bytes that will hold the data
                var dataReceived = [UInt8]()

                // Read data
                let task = session.dataTask(with: request) {(data, response, error) -> Void in

                    if error != nil
                    {
                        print("Request transport error")
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        let response = response as! HTTPURLResponse
                        let data = data!

                        if response.statusCode == 200
                        {
                            //Converting data to String
                            dataReceived = [UInt8](data)
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            print("Request server-side error")
                        }
                    }

                    // Main thread
                    OperationQueue.main.addOperation(
                        {
                            // If downloaded data is less than 2 KB in size, repeat the operation
                            if dataReceived.count <= 2000
                            {
                                self.saveGribFile()
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                self.setWindsAloftDataFromGrib(gribData: dataReceived)

                                // Reset the URL Index back to 0
                                self.urlIndex = 0
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
                task.resume()
            }
        }
    }


// Processing data further
func setWindsAloftDataFromGrib(gribData: [UInt8])
    {
        // Stops spinning activity indicator
        stopActivityIndicator()

        // Other code to process data...
    }

// Makes Web Address

let GRIB_URL = "http://xxxxxxxxxx"

func makeGribWebAddress() -> [String]
    {
        var finalResult = [String]()

        // Main address site
        let address1 = "http://xxxxxxxx"

        // Address part with type of data
        let address2 = "file=gfs.t";
        let address4 = "z.pgrb2.1p00.anl&lev_250_mb=on&lev_450_mb=on&lev_700_mb=on&var_TMP=on&var_UGRD=on&var_VGRD=on"

        let leftlon = "0"
        let rightlon = "359"
        let toplat = "90"
        let bottomlat = "-90"

        // Address part with coordinates
        let address5 = "&leftlon="+leftlon+"&rightlon="+rightlon+"&toplat="+toplat+"&bottomlat="+bottomlat

        // Vector that includes all Grib files available for download
        let listOfFiles = readWebToString()

        if (!listOfFiles.isEmpty)
        {
            for i in 0..<listOfFiles.count
            {
                // Part of the link that includes the file
                let address6 = "&dir=%2F"+listOfFiles[i]

                // Extract time: last 2 characters
                let address3 = listOfFiles[i].substring(from:listOfFiles[i].index(listOfFiles[i].endIndex, offsetBy: -2))

                // Make the link
                let addressFull = (address1 + address2 + address3 + address4 + address5 + address6).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

                finalResult.append(addressFull)
            }
        }

        return finalResult;
    }


func readWebToString() -> [String]
    {
        // Final array to return
        var finalResult = [String]()

        guard let dataURL = NSURL(string: self.GRIB_URL)
            else
        {
            print("IGAGribReader error: No URL identified")
            return []
        }

        do
        {
            // Get contents of the page
            let contents = try String(contentsOf: dataURL as URL)

            // Regular expression
            let expression : String = ">gfs\\.\\d+<"
            let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: contents.characters.count)

            do
            {
                // Match the URL content with regex expression
                let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: expression, options: NSRegularExpression.Options.caseInsensitive)
                let contentsNS = contents as NSString
                let matches = regex.matches(in: contents, options: [], range: range)

                for match in matches
                {
                    for i in 0..<match.numberOfRanges
                    {
                        let resultingNS = contentsNS.substring(with: (match.rangeAt(i))) as String
                        finalResult.append(resultingNS)
                    }
                }

                // Remove "<" and ">" from the strings
                if (!finalResult.isEmpty)
                {
                    for i in 0..<finalResult.count
                    {
                        finalResult[i].remove(at: finalResult[i].startIndex)
                        finalResult[i].remove(at: finalResult[i].index(before: finalResult[i].endIndex))
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                print("IGAGribReader error: No regex match")
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            print("IGAGribReader error: URL content is not read")
        }


        return finalResult;
    }
```

I have been trying to fix it for the past several weeks but in vain. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Unrelated, the use of the operation queue here is completely unnecessary and is inefficient. You're creating a new queue for each request (which is weird ... what is the purpose of "queue" that will only ever have one operation?), then adding the starting of network request (but not the receiving of the response and processing of it) to that queue. I'd suggest losing that operation queue stuff altogether. The nested dispatching of the call to `downloadWindsAloftData`, an asynchronous method, itself, is also very strange.

Comment: Rob. Sorry, the code added. I think without the queue, I did not manage to implement my task, which is going to the next link if the proper data is not loaded. What would you suggest?

Comment: The custom operation queue code here should just be removed. Just create your `URLSessionTask` and `resume` it, and its completion handler is run asynchronously, on background thread for you. And where you do `OperationQueue.main.addOperation { ... }` you should just do  `DispatchQueue.main.async { ... }`. If you're having problem with your asynchronous code, create a nice simple [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and create a new question on that topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your stack trace is telling you that it's stopping at `String(contentsOf:)`, called by `readWebToString`, called by `makeGribWebAddress`.

The problem is that `String(contentsOf:)` performs a synchronous network request. If that request takes any time, it will block that thread. And if you call this from the main thread, your app may freeze.

Theoretically, you could just dispatch that process to a background queue, but that merely hides the deeper problem, that you are doing a network request with an API that is synchronous, non-cancellable, and offers no meaningful error reporting.

You really should doing asynchronous requests with `URLSession`, like you have elsewhere. Avoid using `String(contentsOf:)` with remote URL.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
        let contents = try String(contentsOf: dataURL as URL)
```

You are calling `String(contentsOf: url)` on the main thread (main queue).  This downloads the content of the URL into a string synchronously The main thread is used to drive the UI, running synchronous network code is going to freeze the UI. [This is a big no-no](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/CommonPitfalls/CommonPitfalls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH4-SW9).

You should never call `readWebToString()` in the main queue. Doing `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.downloadWindsAloftData() }` exactly put the block in the main queue which we should avoid. (`async` just means "execute this later", it is still executed on `Dispatch.main`.)

You should just run `downloadWindsAloftData` in the global queue instead of main queue

```
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
        self.downloadWindsAloftData()
    }
```

Only run `DispatchQueue.main.async` when you want to update the UI.